# Ag grid export to csv removing leading zeros to number 1 instead of 00001

Tags: javascript, typescript, export-to-csv, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

Export to csv in ag grid react is removing leading zeros to numeric cells.
ag-grid-enterprise@18.0.1 with react@16.8

This cellStyle working as expected if we download as excel sheet. But not working for Csv download. We need style to be applied for csv as well.

Excel styles object:

```
excelStyles : [{
          id: "textFormat",
          dataType: "string"
        }]
```

pass cellClass in column defs:

```
{
        headerName: "colname",
        field: "field",
        cellClass: "textFormat"
 }
```

Add excelStyles attribute to ag-grid :

```
<AgGridReact excelStyles={excelStyles}....>
```

When we open the csv file in ms excel , we should be able to see cell values as 00001 but not just 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can always process each cell and determine how it gets exportet to CSV:

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-export/#processcellcallback

```
params.processCellCallback = function(params) {
  return parseInt(params.value, 10);
};

this.gridApi.exportDataAsCsv(params);
```